# How to dynamically generate a multi-dataset line graph in GraphJS?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, chart.js

Data is generated like so:

```
$repResults[] = [
    'label' => (new \Carbon\Carbon($wbwResult->created_at))->isoFormat('DD-MM-YY'),
    'data' => [
        # datatype cast to int to prevent {!! xss !!}
        (int) $wbwResult->discipline_three,
        (int) $wbwResult->discipline_four,
        (int) $wbwResult->discipline_five,
        (int) $wbwResult->discipline_six,
    ]
];
```

I am then trying to output the data as a line chart:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.6.0/dist/chart.min.js'></script>
<script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        datasets: {!! json_encode($wbw['reps']) !!},
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
    });
</script>
```

The chart does not render anything, nor do I get any errors in my console. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

The data looks like this:

```
[{"label":"28-11-21","data":[22,70,50,27]},{"label":"28-11-21","data":[7,7,7,7]}]
```

Comment: Hi , see if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati_911/2fav3Lde/) helps .

Comment: Mhm, when I view page source with the updated JS source from your comment, it [renders like this](https://i.imgur.com/wVMcGz6.png) so not sure why this is not working. Ofc, I changed the labels but for SO I just put them as A B C D @Swati

Comment: See that example which i added in my previous comment i have added labels , datasets inside `data` object change that in your code as well onces .

Comment: Thanks!! If you make this an answer I'll mark it as accepted, this fixed my issue and not sure why I didn't see this in the docs @Swati

Comment: Glad to help . Please answer your own question so that it will help others as well :)